# Batch script set new line to variable in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have to write batch script which lists all files in directory and writes that list to file. I wrote some script but I have problem with set new line to variable named LinesToWrite.

Could anyone give me some tip ?

```
@Echo off
set FilesDir= C:\
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set LinesToWrite=
FOR %%f IN (%FilesDir%*.*) DO (
    Set LinesToWrite=!LinesToWrite! Started app with file %%f
    )
Echo !LinesToWrite!>lines.txt
```

Comment: might be easier to append line by line with >> lines.txt

Comment: for your specific error I think you should use %LinesToWrite%

Comment: `(FOR %%f IN (%FilesDir%*.*) DO echo file %%F)>lines.txt`

Comment: @kenny thanks for your reply. You advice is helped ma a a lot!

Comment: @JosefZ thanks for four advice , problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

problem was solved thanks to Kennny i fixed my script , now it looks like this.

```
@Echo off
set FilesDir= C:\
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN (%FilesDir%*.*) DO (
    Echo Started app with file %%f>>Lines.txt
    )
```

Comment: you might want to del Lines.txt at the top of the batch file.

Comment: Thanks , I used Your advice!